# How to listen with PhoneStateListener on dual sim?

Tags: android, phone-state-listener, dual-sim

I am new to android development. trying to make a simple call recorder.

The following `PhoneStateListner` is working perfectly for sim2 incoming and outgoing calls. but call state `CALL_STATE_IDLE` is being called right after `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` when an incoming/outcoming call event occurs in SIM1.

```
AtomicBoolean isRecording = new AtomicBoolean(); 

public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: // Idle... no call
                if (isRecording.get()) {
                    RecordCallService.stopRecording(context);
                    phoneCall = null;
                    isRecording.set(false);
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: // Call answered
                if(!isRecording.get())
                    RecordCallService.startRecording(context, phoneCall);
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: 
                if (null == phoneCall)
                    phoneCall = new CallLog();
                }
                break;
        }

    }
```